# Background colors in Chrome and Atom are no longer uniform

Tags: google-chrome, macos, hdmi, color

Ever since upgrading to macOS Sierra, previously solid background colors in Atom and on certain websites in Chrome are now not uniform. It almost looks like I highlighted stuff with my cursor or something.

It only happens when I plug my mac into an external monitor. If I am working on just my macbook pro screen, everything is normal. When I plug my HDMI into an external monitor, the non-uniform backgrounds start again — including on my macbook pro screen, if mirrored. The HDMI and monitor were checked with other laptops of mine, and the problem never came up. I also tried a different HDMI with the mac, and same problem.

Certain apps like Safari, do not display this problem at all. I've included a screenshot for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling hardware acceleration on Chrome settings. Turn off filevault, check for icc color profiles. In utilities > ColorSync and verify to see errors. It's the GPU i guess, Chrome will active the discrete GPU. Atom is a Chrome App (not shure?). Hope it helps. Looking for a better solution too.

Comment: Turning off hardware acceleration fixed the problem. I also submitted a bug report in hopes the Chrome team issues a fix.